# how to redirect from 1st page to 2nd page when searched in search bar of 1st page and show results on 2nd page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a home page in which it shows results when searched in search bar.

I also have another page, in which if searched in that page, it should redirect to home page and show results based on search in previous page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far?. Please share some sample code.

Comment: assuming you have a working home page with search results you can use query params in the url to pass search values through links.

Comment: `window.location.href = /localhost:8080/search_posts?skills=searchedstring;`  like that i have given but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `action="index.php"` for that search bar form on all pages.

Or you can shift search bar form in a separate file named `search.html` and include that in all.

Comment: Yes but all the main functionality is linked in  home page.